# How to get the only value of a limited SQL query

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am code-reviewing an old Scala fragment, that looks ugly for nowadays:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

val x = spark.sql("SELECT x FROM bigt LIMIT 1")
        .select("x").collect().headOption.get.get(0).toString
```

there are a method that returns one value?

Something more elegant, like:

```
val x = spark.sql("SELECT x FROM bigt LIMIT 1").theOnlyValue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `first`:

```
spark.sql("SELECT x FROM bigt LIMIT 1").as[String].first
```

Comment: Hi, how to do the same with dataframe?  `sqlQuery.toDF.filter("k='foo'").select("x").first` not have an `as[String]`

Comment: Hum.. Seems that I must to return to the old `get(0)` method, it is running:  `sqlQuery.toDF.filter("k='foo'").select("x").first.get(0).toString`